# Is there internal layout with icon and text?

Tags: java, android

I know that there are many iternal layouts which I can use for adapters - android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, etc. But is there any internal layout which I can use for making item with icon and text (image_*_*_text)? Why android.id should I use for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `android.R.layout.activity_list_item`.

EDIT: use either `android.R.id.icon` or `R.id.icon` for the icon, and `android.R.id.text1` for the text.

Comment: What id I use for setting icon? Thank you.